# Retaining a searched value after refreshing, to sort the results. (php)

Tags: php, sorting

I am quite new to PHP and have been following tutorials and notes so far and have run into a problem.The goal is to create an e-commerce website. One function must be to search the database and display products which I can do. These results must then be able to be sorted (by price/name etc.) I can sort the products however I cannot sort the results f the search as I lose the searched term when reloading. Any help on fixing this or improving the work would be fantastic.
Here is what I have so far..

```
<div id = "form">
<form action="search3.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
Search: <input type="text" name="term" /><br />  
<input type="submit" name = "search" value="Submit" />  
</form>  
</div>
```

The form above stores "term" the searched term.

```
<?php 

$term = pg_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);?>
<p>You Searched for:</p><?php Print $term; ?>
<br><br>


Sort by
<form method=get style="display: inline;" name='orderby_form'>
<input type=hidden name='param1' value="<?php print $param1; ?>">
<input type=hidden name='param2' value="<?php print $param2; ?>">
<select name=orderby onChange="orderby_form.submit();">
<option value='none'>v-v-v</option>
<option value='title'>Title</option>
<option value='price_asc'>Price (Low - High)</option>
<option value='price_desc'>Price (High - Low)</option>
</select>
</form>
```

This gives options on how the user wants to sort the data

```
<?php

$selected = array();

$orderby = $_GET['orderby'];
if(!$orderby) 
{ $orderby = ''; }

if($orderby == 'price_asc') 
{
$orderby_query = "order by price asc";
}
else if($orderby == 'price_desc')
{
$orderby_query = "order by price desc";
}
else if($orderby == 'title')
{
$orderby_query = "order by title";
}
else { unset($orderby); }

// If $orderby was valid set the selected sort option for the form.

if($orderby)
{
$selected[$orderby] = 'selected';
}

// Now run your SQL query with the $orderby_query variable.  Ex:

$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE (title LIKE '%$term%' OR description LIKE '%$term%') $orderby_query";

// SQL code goes here..
$result = pg_query($query);
if(pg_num_rows($result) == 0) {
      echo "No records found";
 }
 else{
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
```

After the final bit here I just print the results into tables

These two pictures show the search results.
The first prints all products with "bass" in the title/description and is unsorted.
http://oi61.tinypic.com/28clzqs.jpg

The second is when I sort the data.The search 'term' is lost and ALL products become sorted.
http://oi59.tinypic.com/34g39tu.jpg

Comment: add your `$term` to the 2nd form `<input type=hidden name='term' value="<?php print $term; ?>">`

Comment: Might be better to sort in the UI versus the code. You can display your results and then using JS sort the items on a button click. Otherwise I would change to a `switch()` statement.

Comment: Sean, that is perfect, working grand after that. Such a simple fix I just couldn't see how to make it work at the time.
Since it's working now I may just leave it, but if I get more used to javascript before I finish I may use that instead. So thank you as well, Twisty.

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough work around. Thanks to Sean for showing me.
"add your $term to the 2nd form"

Which is

```
<input type=hidden name='param2' value="<?php print $param2; ?>">
//Added -VV-
<input type=hidden name='term' value="<?php print $term; ?>">
```

Works perfectly well now.